# Modifying x- and yrange?

Tags: gnuplot

The following script:

```
set view map
set dgrid3d 2,2
splot "-" with points title "Data"
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
e
```

plots four dots on the four corners of the diagram. Is there a way to extend the range, so that there is a small margin between the border and the dots?

I know that this can be accomplished using the xrange or yrange commands. But I'd rather like a way to say that a 10pt space is between the outer most point and the border.

A solution like:

1. Get the current xmin and xmax values
2. Do some math stuff with the returned values and set new xmin and xmax values accordingly.

Would be nice as well.

Any hint, link and help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Woltan

Comment: What ultimately are you trying to achieve? How exact do you want to be?  The amount of space will often depend on the terminal you plot the graph to (eg png small or giant) Does it matter if it scales or do you always want 10 pnts no matter the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following possibility to offset the border by some factor:

```
set view map
set dgrid3d 2,2
splot "-" with points title "Data"
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
e
save set "Tmp.txt"
system("python SetRange.py Tmp.txt 1.1")
load "Tmp.txt"
splot "-" with points title "Data"
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
e
```

As you can see, the state of gnuplot is saved in a file Tmp.txt. In other cases if the data is read from a file, the lower splot command could be replaced with a replot.

With the system call you can modify the entries of the xrange and yrange in the temp file. I did that with a python script, since I am not too good with awk^^.

```
import os
import sys

class Range(object):
    def __init__(self, line, factor):
        self.Line = line
        self.Factor = factor
        self.min, self.max = self._GetRange(self.Line)

        self.min_new, self.max_new = self._SetRange(self.min, self.max, self.Factor)

    def Write(self, file):
        Line_new = self.Line[0:self.Line.find("*")]
        Line_new = Line_new + str(self.min_new) + ":" + str(self.max_new)
        Line_new = Line_new + self.Line[self.Line.find("]") : self.Line.find("#")]

        file.write(Line_new + "\n")

    def _GetRange(self, line):
        min, max = (line[line.rfind("[") + 1 : line.rfind("]")]).split(":")
        return (float(min), float(max))

    def _SetRange(self, min, max, factor):
        dist_new = (max - min) * factor
        mean = (max - min) / 2 + min

        min_new = mean - dist_new / 2
        max_new = mean + dist_new / 2
        return (min_new, max_new)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        raise Exception("Cannot find file " + sys.argv[1])

    file = open(sys.argv[1])
    fileContents = file.read().split("\n")
    file.close()

    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        factor = float(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        factor = 1.05

    for line in fileContents:
        if line.find("set xrange") != -1:
            xrange = Range(line, factor)
        elif line.find("set yrange") != -1:
            yrange = Range(line, factor)

    file = open(sys.argv[1], "w")
    xrange.Write(file)
    yrange.Write(file)
    file.close()
```

If there is a shorter way to do that with awk, I'd be more than happy to know ;)

Cherio Woltan

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do.

AFAIK (I'm not an expert on the internals of gnuplot) gnuplot passes much of how the plot is actually be made to the terminal.  So xrange and yrange will be able to give you a little bit extra on either side but how much space this actually is (exactly) will depend upon the size of the plot (so it will be different for png small to png large - for example).

If you want to control the size exactly, then then I think you need to work directly with a specific terminal rather than with gnuplot.  However, Gnuplot does support a wide range of terminals. For this task it is probably easiest to work with the metapost terminal mp.
This lets you alter the positions of the border and tics **exactly**

To get this working you will need your script

```
set term mp latex
set output "xrange_example.mp"
set view map
set dgrid3d 2,2
splot "-" with points title "Data"
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
e
set output 
set term pop
```

And your latex document (presuming you are using this)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{emp,ifpdf}
\ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{xrange_example.0}

\end{document}
```

You then generate your image with

```
> TEX=latex
> gnuplot your_gnuplot.gp
> mpost  xrange_example.mp
> pdflatex xrange.tex
```

It is the xrange_example.mp file that you alter.  If you open it up you will find (about half way down)

```
beginfig(0);
w:=5.000in;h:=3.000in;
a:=w/1200.0;b:=h/720.0;
```

The a and the b specify the scaling to the width and height.
After these add

```
numeric x[], y[];
  x[0] = -10pt;
  x[1] =  10pt;
  y[0] = -10pt;
  y[1] =  10pt;
```

These introduce the distances that you are going to add to the border and the tics.
The tics are defined like so

```
draw (193.0a,591.2b)--(193.0a,569.6b); % On the left
draw (355.8a,165.4b)--(355.8a,187.0b); % on the right
put_text( btex  0.2 etex, 355.8a, 117.8b, 0, 2); % the text
```

You want to modify these like so

```
draw (193.0a+x[0],591.2b)--(193.0a+x[0],569.6b); % On the left
draw (355.8a+x[1],165.4b)--(355.8a+x[1],187.0b); % on the right
put_text( btex  0.2 etex, 355.8a+x[0], 117.8b, 0, 2); % the text
```

As you can see this is *easy to do with search and replace (or in a script) because you are only modifying the numbers 193.0a, 355.8a.*

You need to do the same for xtics and the border

```
draw (192.9a,591.2b)--(192.9a,165.3b)--(1007.0a,165.3b)--(1007.0a,591.2b)--(192.9a,591.2b);
```

In total I think you have to change 8 numbers (lots of times - very scriptable).

As an example, I include the pdf of the `plot sin(x)` with the modified border.  The border has been modified by **exactly 10pt**. (you could equally choose this in mm or cm or inches etc)

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, thx for the very elaborate posting! It is an interesting idea and it does exactly what I want. I'll definitely keep that solution in mind. However, I'd prefer not to make the detour over latex. Maybe there is way to make this work from within gnuplot?!?