# Gnuplot: canvas size

Tags: canvas, gnuplot

when plotting my data using gnuplot, I experience that the right border is cut off, so the last x value is not completely visible.
How can I set the canvas to be larger?

[image: plot]

Comment: Looks like you want to actually enlarge the canvas, with a wider margin.  A combination of both answers.

Comment: btw, you were the first answer given in a Google search - April 2018 - Thanks.  Here was the next answer:  http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node31.html

Comment: One other trick is to use the `Imagemagick` tools to resize the final plot file after you have the margins set.  I use the `montage` tool to gather plots made from several different computers to create https://www.SDsolarBlog.com/montage - It enforces their final sizes to fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Second Answer

To enlarge the margins the plot see [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-20200043.36). So something like:

```
set rmargin 5
```

should do the trick.

#### First Answer

You can explicitly set the [xrange](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-29700043.88) like so:

```
set xrange [0:1e8]
```

Alternatively you can specify the range in your [plot](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-10100034) command:

```
plot [0:1e8] ...
```

If you want to dynamically alter the x- and y-range maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106434/572616) can help.

Comment: The range is fine, I want the white area on the right to be larger so we can read 1e+007

Answer (score 36):

Being pretty much annoyed by a tiny Gnuplot window making use of just a humble tile of my screen and `xrange`/`yrange` just fitting more/less data into the very same tiny window, I have came to exactly the question: "How to increase the canvas area?". The answer I've found (being exactly what I was looking for) is

```
set terminal wxt size 1300,600
```

where 1300 is the width and 600 is the height. The option of specifying size for the `wxt` terminal is said to be only available in the latest Gnuplot versions (for example 4.2 is said to be missing it) but it works just fine for my 4.4.

Comment: The set terminal command sets the output type.  `wxt` is a specific output type.  You can substitute `jpeg` or whatever your output type is, and use the size command after as shown.

Comment: And if on macos "terminal aqua"

Comment: How to make the script portable? I want to use the default terminal.