# chart is flipped when using multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot two charts (reading the same data points) using multiplot. The purpose is to put the second (smaller) chart in the right of the first (bigger) chart.

The code is

```
set term post eps enhanced color blacktext size 4,4 solid "Times-Roman" 14
set output 'cla.ps'

set multiplot

# draw bottom and left lines
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
set border 3


# increasing the canvas size
set rmargin 50
set tmargin 2

# put the big chart, it will not use the whole space
set origin 0,0
set size 1.2,0.5

plot 'test.txt' u 1 with points lc rgb "black" 

# put the small char in the right
set origin 0.6,0.2
set size 0.2,0.2
plot 'test.txt' u 1 with points lc rgb "black" 

# always unset multiplot
unset multiplot
```

Problem is, the second chart is shown in a mirror fashion (horizontal flip). But I didn't such an option. How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should give you a nice warning explaining that: `warning: Terminal canvas area too small to hold plot. Check plot boundary and font sizes.`

With `set rmargin 50` you set the right margin to be 50 character widths. That applies also to the second plot unless you use e.g. `set rmargin -1` to reset it to automatic calculation.

But I don't see any sense to set both the size and the rmargin. Setting the rmargin does *not* increase the canvas size, like you suggest in your comments.

Here is a working example:

```
set term post eps enhanced color blacktext size 4,2 solid "Times-Roman" 14
set output 'cla.ps'

set multiplot

# draw bottom and left lines
unset tics
set border 3

# put the big chart, it will not use the whole space
set origin 0,0
set size 0.8,1

plot x**2

# put the small char in the right
set origin 0.75,0.2
set size 0.25,0.3
plot x

# always unset multiplot
unset multiplot
```

That gives you the output (tested with 4.6.5):

[image]

Comment: But I agree with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535400/gnuplot-canvas-size that margins can change the canvas size

Comment: No, the canvas size is given by the `set terminal postscript size 4,2`, which sets the canvas size (i.e. the image size) to 4 inches wide and 2 inches high. If you use `set rmargin 5` you shrink the plot size relative to the canvas size.